# NoSuchMethodError on calling MenuItem.collapseActionView

Tags: android, android-actionbar, android-support-library, searchview, android-actionbar-compat

Using android support library I implemented *ActionBar* (android.support.v7.app.ActionBar).
Meanwhile I was trying to interact with *SearchView* and tried to collapse *SearchItem*  using below method:

```
 searchItem.collapseActionView();
```

seachItem is of type MenuItem.
This lead to below exception:

```
java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: android.view.MenuItem.collapseActionView
```

So how should i collapse SearchItem?

Answer (score 22, accepted):

Instead of using:

```
searchItem.collapseActionView();
```

I must use static method from ***android.support.v4.view.MenuItemCompat***:

```
MenuItemCompat.collapseActionView(searchItem);
```

It seems to obvious at the moment but it took several hours to wonder that available codes at websites usually intended to run on ***(android.app.ActionBar)*** library (API 11 and higher) not on Support Library V7 ***(android.support.v7.app.ActionBar)*** which got its own methods that are different in some cases like this.

Comment: Where on the earth were you all these days :)
Thanks.